# Finding Eigenvector from eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Given the constant matrix \begin{bmatrix}-3&4&-2\\1&0&1\\6&-6&5\end{bmatrix} find the fundamental matrix.

After, finding the corresponding eigenvalues which are $\lambda$ = 2,1,&-1, when trying to find the eigenvector  for $\lambda$=2, I end up with the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}-5&4&-2\\1&-2&1\\6&-6&3\end{bmatrix}, then after trying to find the corresponding eigenvector I end up with 
u=(0,1,2), which I obtained from the reduced matrix

\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&-.5\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

what does the final matrix imply? Does it mean that x=0, y=free parameter and z=2y, i.e. if y=1, then x=0 and z=2y?

Comment: What is a fundamental matrix?

Comment: That eigenvector is correct for $\lambda=2$. How did you get that third matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&-.5\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 0\\y\\2y\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}  $$
 That is the eigenvector has the form $(0,y, 2y)$ as you indicated.

Now you need to find other eigenvectors  and  find the fundamental solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @J.Garcia   Thanks for your attention and  understanding.